# How can i implement setinterval into my ajax script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, setinterval

I am filling a html table when the page loads using ajax, the ajax grabs the data from a json file, it works well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "order": [
        [0, "desc"]
    ],
    "ajax": "data.json",
    "deferRender": true,
    rowReorder: {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
    },
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [{
            responsivePriority: 2,
            targets: 0
        },
        {
            responsivePriority: 10001,
            targets: 2
        },
        {
            responsivePriority: 1,
            targets: -1
        }
    ]
  });
});
```

I would like to use setinterval() to reload the table every 5 seconds, i have tried adding:

```
mytable();
setInterval(mytable, 30000);
```

at the bottom of the script, however this does not work, i assume i need to use something else instead of 'mytable', however i'm not sure what i need to use.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What does the `mytable` function do and where do you get and load the data?

Comment: mytable is the name of the html table

Comment: And you're calling it like a function?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use the function you already use as the interval's target function?

Comment: Yes, my bad i didn;t realise it had to be a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a **function** called `mytable`, you have an HTML element with an **ID** of `mytable`. You are using an anonymous function in the AJAX call. But, if you extract that function and change it into a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), then your approach will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  fillTable();                  // Run the function
  setInterval(fillTable, 5000); // Then run it every 5 seconds after that
});

// Create a function declaration so you can refer to
// to the function by name later.
function fillTable(){
  $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "order": [
        [0, "desc"]
    ],
    "ajax": "data.json",
    "deferRender": true,
    rowReorder: {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
    },
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [{
            responsivePriority: 2,
            targets: 0
        },
        {
            responsivePriority: 10001,
            targets: 2
        },
        {
            responsivePriority: 1,
            targets: -1
        }
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: hi Scott, im getting an error for this, chrome says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )'  and jshint.com says: Four warnings
13 Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.
13 Missing semicolon.
15 Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
15 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Comment: @JonnyP Sorry about that. I've updated the answer. There does need to be an anonymous function as the argument to `document.ready`, but your named function should be in that anonymous function. Try again with the updated code.

Comment: No probs, I feel like i am closer now, table is loading, however every 5 seconds i get 'DataTables warning: table id=mytable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3' and it fails to reload

Comment: Fixed by adding "destroy" : true,
Thanks

Comment: @JonnyP Glad you got it working, but please understand that the `destroy` part was a separate issue from the question you've posted here and thus my answer.

Comment: thanks but how can i get it working without destroy ? it gives me error because it could not reinitalize table

Comment: I'm not saying that you can get it working without `destroy`. I'm saying that your initial question wasn't about the AJAX call itself, it was about using `setInterval()`, which is what my answer addresses. When you have situations where solving one problem leads to another, it's best to post another question that specifically addresses that new problem. Or, as you did here, just add a comment for others to see about the new problem and how you solved it.